# Rasa NLU for complex paragraphs

Tags: rasa-nlu

I have seen many examples that Rasa NLU is very good and efficient for building chatbot solutions. Means it is efficient to find intent and entity out of small chat conversations.

But is it preferable to find the intent from complex paragraphs as well? For example is it capable to use for long emails?

Comment: Yes, the better you train it the better will be. I've been using Rasa NLU to sort assistance emails and it works pretty good.

Comment: Hey thanks. Any online reference to the accuracy it achieved for assistance emails?

Comment: Not that I know of. I wrote it as a comment because it is mainly opinion-based. My need were to understand if an email was either a technical issue or an account issue or other tags, and it almost never fails. When it fails it is because it cannot find the correct entity among a correct intent (This is because sometimes users don't write emails properly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasa NLU is most suited for shorter messages since it was built for contextual AI assistants. You can still try running it on larger paragraphs, but you probably need to add a lot of data. Maybe some approaches such as [Doc2Vec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec#Extensions) might be better suited here.